# jQueryで要素の横幅（width）を拡大縮小するには？

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery初心者です。
Googleで調べまくったのですが、やり方が見当たらず…。皆さん教えて下さい。

既に、CSSでwidthを100pxで設定している要素に対して、
jQueryを使って「"#btn"をクリックすると"#box"の幅が20pxずつ縮小する」
という指示は出来ないものでしょうか。

```js
$("#btn").on("click",function(){
  $("#box").css('width', '-20px');
});
```

では出来ませんでした。（そらそうなんですが、最適なやり方が思いつかず…）
実現したいこととしては、boxの右側から20pxずつ削れていって、
５回クリックすると0pxになるようにしたいのです。

ご協力をお願いしますm(_ _ )m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

widthメソッドを呼び出す方法があります。

```js
$("#btn").on("click",function(){
    $("#box").width("-=20");
});
```

または、width内に関数を指定する方法があります。

```js
$("#btn").on("click",function(){
    $("#box").width(function(i, w) { return w - 20; });
});
```

なお、HTMLページロード時にclickイベントの定義を読み込む場合は、

```js
<script>
$(function(){
    //ここにコード
});
</script>
```

内にコードを記述してください。
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Ref: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/use-width-to-decrease-width-of-element

Comment: うまく動作しました！ありがとうございます。

Comment: すみません。追加で聞かせてくださいm(_ _ )m　①#boxのwidthが50pxになると#boxの"background-color"を赤色に、②20pxになると"background-color"をオレンジ色に、③最後、0pxになった際に画像（"./img/finish.jpg"）が現れる。としたい場合は、jQueryの追加記述をどのようにすれば宜しいでしょうか？　＊おそらく、if文になると思いますが…。

Comment: 新しい質問を作成してください。